# SQLite syntax for If Else condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite database. My table has a text column called "Password". Earlier for retrieving the values I used to execute a simple `select * from myTable` query. But now the requirement is that if Password value is not `NULL` then I need to show it as "Yes" or otherwise "No". It's something like:

```
select * from myTable
if Password != NULL then Password = 'Yes'
else Password = 'No'
```

I searched a lot regarding this but I didn't get any proper link or example.
Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: NEVER compare anything with NULL (`!=NULL`). Instead use IS NULL (IS NOT NULL). Because this condition is ALWAYS FALSE `NULL=NULL -> FALSE NULL!=NULL -> FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks Valex. I actially am using (<>'') instead of (IS NOT NULL)

Comment: Question is old but for all still reading this, please always use IS NULL / IS NOT NULL as expression, neither ==, != nor <>.

Comment: The Coalesce Sql command allows for a default value when a field is null, it is supported by SQLITE: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce

Answer (score 93):

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN Password IS NOT NULL
       THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END AS PasswordPresent
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 20):

SQLite uses the CASE WHEN THEN END syntax. You can read more about that here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

I have not checked the syntax but I'm guessing something like this:

```
select * 
from myTable CASE WHEN Password != NULL THEN Password = 'Yes' ELSE Password = 'No' END;
```

Though I'm not sure that would work at all. If you're trying to get a YES or NO based on the presence of a password in the table for every record, perhaps this is closer to what you want:

```
SELECT Field1, 
    Field2,
    (CASE WHEN Password != NULL THEN 
        'Yes' 
     ELSE 
        'No' 
     END) as 'Password'
FROM myTable;
```

Again, I do not currently have access to SQLite to test this myself so it probably needs some work.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I will try working on your suggestion. It's correct, I need to check the presence of Password in every record. But even in your 2nd suggestion use of "select * ..." would be more convenient. Anyway I will try implementing them and reply you with the feedback.

Comment: Note that `Password != NULL` will always be true, since comparing something with NULL is not possible, like how you can't compare anything to nothing. You should use `WHEN Password IS NOT NULL` instead.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`IIF()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#iif) function from SQLite v3.32.0+ to shorten your code even more:

```
SELECT
  Password,
  IIF(Password IS NOT NULL, 'Yes', 'No') [HasPassword]
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand we want to change the value of the password column to "YES" if password has been written in the password column otherwise we change the value to "NO".

We can use the following two queries to make these changes :

```
UPDATE myTable SET Password = "YES" WHERE Password IS NOT NULL;    
UPDATE myTable SET Password = "NO" WHERE PASSWORD IS NULL;
```

Comment: poster did not ask to modify the table