# SQLite conditionals in creation of a trigger

Tags: sqlite, triggers, conditional-statements, where-clause, sql-insert

I'm creating a trigger using SQLite and I want to compare if the OLD value is different than the NEW value so I can execute an `INSERT`

This is the trigger I created but seems like the MySQL syntax does not work in SQLite.
What would be the equivalent?

```
CREATE TRIGGER document_handler AFTER UPDATE ON document
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.type <> OLD.type THEN
        INSERT INTO DocumentUpdates (id_document, attribute_changed, lastvalue, newvalue, modification_date)
        VALUES (id, "type", OLD.type, NEW.type, NOW());
    END IF;
    
    IF NEW.title <> OLD.title THEN
        INSERT INTO DocumentUpdates (id_document, attribute_changed, lastvalue, newvalue, modification_date)
        VALUES (id, "title", OLD.title, NEW.title, NOW());
    END IF;
    
    IF NEW.path <> OLD.path THEN
        INSERT INTO DocumentUpdates (id_document, attribute_changed, lastvalue, newvalue, modification_date)
        VALUES (id, "path", OLD.path, NEW.path, NOW());
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Try using case/when statement instead of if/then, as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580294/sqlite-syntax-for-if-else-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite there is no `IF` conditional statement.

In this case you can use simple `WHERE` clauses:

```
CREATE TRIGGER document_handler AFTER UPDATE ON document
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO DocumentUpdates (id_document, attribute_changed, lastvalue, newvalue, modification_date)
  SELECT NEW.id, 'type', OLD.type, NEW.type, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE NEW.type IS NOT OLD.type;

  INSERT INTO DocumentUpdates (id_document, attribute_changed, lastvalue, newvalue, modification_date)
  SELECT NEW.id, 'title', OLD.title, NEW.title, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE NEW.title IS NOT OLD.title;
    
  INSERT INTO DocumentUpdates (id_document, attribute_changed, lastvalue, newvalue, modification_date)
  SELECT NEW.id, 'path', OLD.path, NEW.path, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE NEW.path IS NOT OLD.path;
END;
```

I changed all `<>` with `IS NOT` which can compare also `NULL` values.
Also, the equivalent of `NOW()` in SQLite is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=293d092ec28fdd44a07cd4dbf1570c03).